# Sorting hashes on value length whilst preserving order

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, key

I'm currently writing a Perl script to sort lines from stdin and print the lines in order of line length whilst preserving order for the ones that are equal.
My sorting code consists of the following:

```
while (my $curr_line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($curr_line);
    $lines{$curr_line} = length $curr_line;
}

for my $line (sort{ $lines{$a} <=> $lines{$b} } keys %lines){
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

For example my stdin consists of the following:

```
tiny line
medium line
big line
huge line
rand line
megahugegigantic line
```

I'd get the following output:

```
big line
rand line
tiny line
huge line
medium line
megahugegigantic line
```

Is there any way I can preserve the order for lines of equal length such that tiny would come before huge which comes before rand? Also, the order seems to change everytime I run the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with sort Perl uses the quick sort algorithm which is a stable sort, inputs that match the same sort key have the same order on output of the sort as input.

Your problem is that you are storing the lines in a hash. A hash is an unordered collection of key value pairs so adding the lines to the hash and then printing them out again with out the sort will give you the lines in a random order.

You need to read all the lines into an array and then sort them on length, the quickest way being to use a [Schwartzian Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) see below.

```
my  @lines = <STDIN>;
chomp(@lines);

my @sorted = # This is the clever bit and needs to be red from the last map up
    map { $_->[0] } # Get the lines
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }  # Sort on length
    map { [$_, length $_] } # Create a list of array refs containing
        # the line and the length of the line
    @lines;

print join "\n", @sorted; # print out the sorted lines
```

Comment: `print join "\n", LIST` is a bad idea because it will leave the last line of the output unterminated. And it is no shorter than the proper `print "$_\n" for LIST`.

Comment: `my  @lines = <STDIN>` will require the operator to use Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows) to terminate the input. That's an ugly user interface, and you should allow a blank input line to end the list. The OP has `while ( my $curr_line = <STDIN> )` but that won't terminate either because the input will always contain a newline. The best way is `last unless $curr_line =~ /\S/` within the loop.

Comment: Please don't mislead people into unnecessary optimisation in a vain attempt to show off. You should never add optimisation until you have written straightforward working code and found it to be too slow. In any case, a *Schwartzian Transform* is likely to be slower than using `sort { length $a <=> length $b } @lines` because `length` is extremely fast.

Answer (score 3):

### One possible solution

You can save the position of the line in the input file handle as well as the `length`. The [`$.` magic variable (*input line number*)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) provides this. You can then sort on both values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lines;
while ( my $curr_line = <DATA> ) {
  chomp($curr_line);
  $lines{$curr_line} = [ length $curr_line, $. ];
}

for my $line (
  sort {
       $lines{$a}->[0] <=> $lines{$b}->[0]
    || $lines{$a}->[1] <=> $lines{$b}->[1]
  } keys %lines
) {
  print $line, "\n";
}

__DATA__
tiny lin1
medium line
big line
huge lin2
rand lin3
megahugegigantic line
```

This will always output

```
big line
tiny lin1
huge lin2
rand lin3
medium line
megahugegigantic line
```

You can of course use a hash to make the code more readable, too.

```
$lines{$curr_line} = { 
  length   => length $curr_line, 
  position => $., 
};
```

---

### Explanation of your implementation

Your results changed their order every time because of random hash ordering. The way `keys` returns the list of keys is random, because of the way Perl implements hashes. This is by design, and a security feature. Since there are several keys that have the same value, the sort will sometimes return different results, based on which of the equal value keys came out first.

You could mitigate this by sticking another `sort` in front of your `keys` call. That would sort the keys by name, at least making the order of the undesired result be consistent.

```
#                                               vvvv
for my $line (sort{ $lines{$a} <=> $lines{$b} } sort keys %lines) { ... }
```

---

Note that you don't have to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the input if you put the `\n` back when you `print`. It's always of the same length anyway. If you do, you should `print` a `$/`, which is the [*input record separator*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2F) that `chomp` removed, or you falsify your data.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere do you store the original order, so you can't possibly sort by it. The easiest fix is to store the lines in an array, and ensure that Perl is using a stable sort.

```
use sort 'stable';

my @lines = <>;
chomp(@lines);

for my $line ( sort { length($a) <=> length($b) } @lines) {
   say $line;
}
```

[ *ST is overkill for this. It' such overkill that it probably even slows things down!* ]

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained, the randomness comes from your use of hash keys to store the strings. There is no need for this, or anything more elaborate like a *Schwartzian Transform*, to make this work

All Perl versions since v5.8 have used a *stable* sort, which will keep values that sort equally in the same order. But you can insist that the `sort` operator you get is a stable one using the `sort` pragma with

```
use sort 'stable'
```

Here's how I would write your program. It stops reading input at end of file, or when it sees a blank line in case you want to enter the data from the keyboard

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';
use sort 'stable';

my @list;

while ( <> ) {
    last unless /\S/;
    chomp;
    push @list, $_;
}

say for sort { length $a <=> length $b } @list;
```

Using the same input as you use in the question, this produces

#### output

```
big line
tiny line
huge line
rand line
medium line
megahugegigantic line
```